# Laravel Indirect modification of overloaded property error when saving to database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save my eloquent model with its relationship.

According to documentation, this is how you save it.

```
    $post = App\Post::find(1);

    $post->comments[0]->message = 'Message';
    $post->comments[0]->author->name = 'Author Name';

    $post->push();
```

This is my initial code:

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = request()->name;
    $user->username = request()->username;
    $user->email = request()->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make(request()->password);
    $user->profile->account_number = request()->account_number;
    $user->push();
```

and it throws me the "Indirect modification of overloaded property" error.

My fix is:

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = request()->name;
    $user->username = request()->username;
    $user->email = request()->email;
    $user->password = Hash::make(request()->password);
    $user->save();

    $profile = new Profile;
    $profile->user_id = $user->id;
    $profile->account_number = request()->account_number;
    $profile->save();
```

What is missing in my first code for it to work? I really think it will work like that with the push() method.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the profile does not exist yet.  You are trying to modify a property of `null`.

```php
$user->profile

// null
```

```php
$user->profile->account_number 

// Indirect modification of overloaded property
```

However, you can use the relationship like this after the user is saved.

```php
// ...

$user->save();

$user->profile()->save(new Profile([
    'account_number' => request()->account_number
]));
```

And once both models exist, you can use the relationship like this.

```php
$user->profile->account_number = request()->account_number;
$user->push();
```

Comment: Nope, that still produces Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$profile has no effect ERROR.

Comment: I rolled back some edits because I was trying to work around your original method.  Please check the latest updates.  You can't use the last method unless both models exist (are saved).